# Unipotent matrices are conjugate to their inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, unipotent-matrices

An element $a$ in a ring $R$ is called *unipotent* if $(1-a)^k=0$ for some positive integer $k$. Let $F$ be a field and $n$ a positive integer. It is not difficult to see that each unipotent element in the ring of matrices over $F$ is of forms an upper triangular matrix whose main diagonal entries are $1$. According to [4', Page 302](https://sci-hub.se/10.1007/bf00181192), each unipotent matrix is a product of at most two elements of order $2$. Recall that an element $a$ of order $2$ means $a^2=1$. Observe that a product of at most two elements of order $2$ is conjugate to its inverse, and thus any unipotent matrix is conjugate to its inverse.

I would like to ask whether it is true in general, that is, any unipotent element in an arbitrary ring is conjugate to its inverse. Observe that if $x$ is an unipotent element in a ring $R$, then $$x^{-1}=(1-(1-x))^{-1}=1+(1-x)+(1-x)^2+\cdots+(1-x)^{k-1}.$$ Therefore, we need find an element $a$ in $R$ such that $x=ax^{-1}a^{-1}$, that is, $xa=ax^{-1}$. However, I do not know the existence of such an element. Any counterexample or reference or technique is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to ask whether it is true in general, that is, any unipotent element in an arbitrary ring is conjugate to its inverse.

For a counterexample we only need to find an unipotent element of a commutative ring that is not self-inverse.
We can consider for simplicity the rings $ℤ/nℤ$.
For these rings, the smallest counterexample are the elements $4$ and $7$ in $ℤ/9ℤ$.

##### Addendum

> I would like to ask whether each unipotent element in a non-commutative ring can be expressed as a product of finite elements $a_1, a_2, \dotsc, a_m$ in which each $a_i$ is conjugate to $a_i^{-1}$.

Take some noncommutative ring $S$ and consider $R ≔ ℤ/9ℤ × S$.
The ring $R$ is also noncommutative, and the elements $(4, 1)$ and $(7, 1)$ of $R$ are unipotent.

If $(4, 1)$ had the desired form, then by projecting on the first coordinate, $4$ would also have the desired form.
That is, there would exist elements $a_1, \dotsc, a_n$ of $ℤ/9ℤ$ such that $4 = a_1 \dotsm a_n$, each $a_i$ is invertible, and each $a_i$ is conjugated to its inverse.
As $ℤ/9ℤ$ is commutative, this would mean that each $a_i$ is self-inverse.

The invertible elements of $ℤ/9ℤ$ are $1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8$, of which only $1$ and $8$ are self-inverse.
But the only elements that can be represented as elements of the form $b_1 \dotsm b_m$ with $b_i ∈ \{1, 8\}$ are $1$ and $8$, precisely because these two elements commute and are self-inverse.
Therefore, $4$ is not of the desired form.
(We could also have used $7$ instead of $4$.)

Comment: I would like to ask whether each unipotent element in a non-commutative ring can be expressed as a product of finite elements $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_m$ in which each $a_i$ is conjugate to $a_i^{-1}$. For instance, as a result of X. Hou, I know when $2$ is invertible, each element in the unit upper triangular matrix group $\mathrm{UT}_n(R)$ over a ring $R$ is a product of at most four elements of order $2$, and thus it is a product of at most two elements I want.

Comment: @TranNamSon No, it’s not possible, basically by the same example.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jendrik Stelzner.